# Importing texts from MS document then transforming them into bold texts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ms-word, tuples

I wanted to import texts from word document then transform them into **bold** (depending on the word lenght) then put the texts back into word document. For example: I take words into a list or tuple

```
test_word = "here is a sentnce u can print out in differnt collers and bold the text"

print (test_word.split())
```

output:

```
['here', 'is', 'a', 'sentnce', 'u', 'can', 'print', 'out', 'in', 'differnt', 'collers', 'and', 'bold', 'the', 'text']
```

Then I wanted to take the output even transform it depending on the len of the string I wanted to bold certain texts:

['**her**e', '**is**', 'a', '**sent**nce', '**u**', '**can**', 'print', '**out**', 'in', 'di**ffe**rnt', '**col**lers', 'and', '**bold**', '**the**', '**te**xt'] etc

So far I could not find real **bold** in python modules is there any python modules that works with MS word?:

```
class color:

   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

print(color.BOLD + 'Hello World !' + color.END)
```

Comment: Take a look at the python-docx module. This website shows how you can do this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-text-in-python-docx-module/

Comment: Thanks, How do I add logic to the ( add_run(" text ").bold=True) method? take the string and then make them into tuples and add (if) logic on the (len) method to bold certain texts?

Answer (score 0):

The best library for this case is probably `python-docx`. You can review the [official documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and this [article on some specific uses](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-text-in-python-docx-module/). In particular, Example 3 may be useful for helping you to format bold text!